# NULL при return в функции для получения месяца

Tags: php

Я хочу вывести месяц, но что-то идёт не так и `$month` возвращает `NULL`
`$cat['pubdate']` - тут я получаю строку в виде `2019-12-18 12:11:57`
`$monthIndex = intval($monthIndex);` - то что получил в функции, я пытаюсь преобразовать в число, думая, что мне поможет(нет)
Если написать так, написав число `echo $month(1);`, то всё выводится отлично

```php
$months = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];
$time = strtotime($cat['pubdate']);
$month = function($monthIndex) use ($months) {
    $monthIndex = intval($monthIndex);
    return $months[$monthIndex];
};

$date = date('m', $time);
echo $month($date);
```

Comment: И что же выводится при ручном вызове `echo $month(1);`? Не февраль, случайно? Посмотрите внимательно.

Comment: В PHP как и в JavaScript индексация массивов начинается с нуля.

Comment: Покажите в каком формате у Вас $cat['pubdate']

Comment: Ну ладно. Что вокруг да около ходить. Исправьте вот так: `return $months[$monthIndex-1];`

Comment: @ВЛ80 о боже, как я мог об этом не подумать, спасибо большое

Comment: @ВЛ80 создадите ответ? Я вам галочку поставлю

Comment: Спасибо. Да там уже ответ дали с двумя вариантами. Я не против, если вы там поставите галочку.

Comment: @ВЛ80 я не против, если Вы создадите ответ. Я свой удалю. Цель - помочь, а не заработать очков.)

Comment: @ВЛ80, хорошо, просто мне такой ответ не нравится, я бы такое не писал, и в моём примере можно убрать `$monthIndex = intval($monthIndex);` так как это ничего особо не делает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
$cat = "2019-12-26 20:45:36";
$date_m = [
    'января',
    'февраля',
    'марта',
    'апреля',
    'мая',
    'июня',
    'июля',
    'августа',
    'сентября',
    'октября',
    'ноября',
    'декабря'
];
$month = date('n', strtotime($cat))-1;
$data = $date_m[$month];
```

Вариант 2:

```
$cat1 = "2019-12-26 20:45:36";

$cat['pubdate'] = $cat1;

$months = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];
$time = strtotime($cat['pubdate']);
$month = function($monthIndex) use ($months) {
    $monthIndex = intval($monthIndex) - 1;
    return $months[$monthIndex];
};

$date = date('m', $time);
echo $month($date);
```

Вариант 3, который использовал автор вопроса:

```php
$months = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];
$time = strtotime($cat['pubdate']);
$month = function($monthIndex) use ($months) {
    return $months[$monthIndex-1];
};

echo $month(date('m', $time));
```

Comment: Экзотический вариант 3: `$months = ['нульваря', 'января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', ...`

Comment: можно и без экзотики `[1 => "января", "февраля", ...]`